# URL with parameters does not find static files Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm making a URL with parameters but it does not find the static files because it adds the name of the URL to the location of the static files, with normal urls this does not happen (I already have some pages working like this).

This is a url without parameters
[image: This is a url without parameters]

This is a url with parameters
[image: This is a url with parameters]

Look that add 'validador' to static file urls

This is the function:

```py
def validador(request, id):
    context                    = {}
    context['browser_mobile']  = detect_browser_type(request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    context['id'] = id
    return render(request, 'validador.html', context)
```

URLs file:

```py
from django.urls import path


app_name='torredecontrol'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', inicio, name='inicio'),
    path('iniciativa', iniciativa, name='iniciativa'),
    path('agregar_iniciativa', agregarIniciativa, name='add_iniciativa'),
    path('validador/<int:id>', validador, name='validadores'),
```

Comment: please provide code not images of code

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I'm sorry n the rush I forgot that I could put code

Comment: "parameters" are not involved here at all. The issue smells like relative URL. Please show the template code where you link static files and part of settings.py related to static files.